# Zend PDF current page number in footer

Tags: zend-pdf

I use Zend PDF to generate PDF. I want to show a page number on each page in the footer. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple way to display a page number on the bottom right corner of each page :

```
$number_pages = sizeof($pdf->pages);

foreach($pdf->pages AS $key => $page) {
    $page->setFillColor(new Zend_Pdf_Color_GrayScale(0));
    $page->drawText(($key + 1) . "/$number_pages", 540, 15, 'UTF-8');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not a feature that is built into Zend PDF, so you will need to implement it yourself.